# How to set username/password in windows server for accessing a Domain Controller?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, domaincontroller

I cannot connect to Domain Controller (Active Directory) from a windows server due to DM's user/password. I get the error:

> The following Domain Controller could not be contacted: xxx. The user name or password is incorrect.

I want to set an AD user by using the *Active Directory Users and Computers* tool from the windows server. Even if the windows-server can reach the Domain Controller, it cannot log in to manage and add users, for example.

QUESTION: Where/how do I set username/password in windows-server for login and manage the Domain Controller?

[image]

Comment: Please add the user in Adminsitrator group and give delegate control to read and write of other users.

Comment: I am logged in this windows-server as Administrator already. Are you suggesting to add Administrator user to Administrator group on the local windows-server?
 
I think you misunderstood the problem: I cannot access the Active Directory service, so I cannot manage users/groups in AD.

Comment: are you asking how you can access and manage the Active Directory from a admin or local user ?

Comment: yes. How can I access AD service on the network, from the Administrator that is on a different windows-server? I know the AD's pwd to access it, but I don't know how to tell the windows server to use it to access the AD service. I want to manage users/groups on the AD service from a different windows-server.

Comment: The different window server should be a member of the same authoritative domain of which the domain controller has pubhslihed ie if you created a domain controller with domain contoso.com then different window sever should a member of this domain.. once the window server become the member of contoso.com. you can access the AD service.

Answer (score 1):

I did test in my environment I am able to successfully connect to domain controller (Active Directory) from a different server.

**Please Follow the below Steps :**

Step 1: Created one Server with name `ansumantestserv`**(domain controller).**

Step 2: created another server (different server) with name `ansumantest2`.

Step 3: Added the IP address(private) of `ansumantestserv` in preferred DNS Server of `ansumantest2`

[image].

Step 4: added the same IP address in Virtual Network’s DNS server and ansumantest2 ->Network Interface -> DNS Server.

[image]

[image]

Step 5: Added the domain name in `ansumantest2` and finally second server connect to domain controller.

[image]

Below is the **screenshot** for one user can able to login to both server as both server added in domain contoso.com.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of login as local wiundows-server administrator, login as AD administrator, by prepending the netBIOS name and by using the AD administrator password.

[image]